# Ruby and Rails paperclip error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I don't know whats wrong: When I lunch rails server, it generate error.

```
$ rails server
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
.../config/environments/development.rb
:43:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `paperclip' for #<...:Application:0x61ad108> (NameError)
```

I installed gems in gemfile:

```
gem 'thin'
gem 'protected_attributes'
gem 'paperclip' , '~> 4.2'
```

Than, I specify environments/development.rb:

```
paperclip.options[:image_magick_path] = "d:/Ruby21/ImageMagick"
#ENV['PATH'] = Paperclip.options[:command_path] + ";" + ENV['PATH']
```

Comment: I forgot to add: ImageaMagick in installed in folder d:/Ruby21/ImageMagick

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't, run `bundle install` to install your new gems.

Comment: already done!  $ bundle show paperclip

D:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/paperclip-4.2.1

Answer (score 0):

In your development.rb file, I believe that `paperclip.options[:image_magick_path] = "d:/Ruby21/ImageMagick"` should actually be `Paperclip.options[:image_magick_path] = "d:/Ruby21/ImageMagick"` - call 'options' on the Class, not an instance.